# How to convert external data into an array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, import, sage

I am loading some external data that looks like:

```
[[1 0 0][1 1 1][0 1 1]]
```

(no commas) into my code that requires arrays to run. I would like the code to look like:

```
np.array([[1 0 0],[1 1 1],[0 1 1]])
```

I'm not sure how to covert this to an array.

I've tried treating it as a list but that doesn't work.

Comment: What format exactly is the external data in? A string?

Comment: This is a malformed array of lists np.array([[1 0 0],[1 1 1],[0 1 1]]). It should be np.array([[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1],[0, 1, 1]]).  Do you agree?

Comment: That's what the print of numpy looks like.  It's not intended for saving or conversion back to an array. If the array is large enough it will contain ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

I will use ast and replace some chars with comma.

```
import ast
txt = "[[1 0 0][1 1 1][0 1 1]]".replace('][', '],[').replace(' ', ',')
np.array(ast.literal_eval(txt))

Result:
array([[1, 0, 0],[1, 1, 1],[0, 1, 1]])
```

Reference: https://docs.python.org/2/library/ast.html